# Intercepting pastefromclipboard message outside of the TMemo, TEdit control

Tags: delphi

I have a component, which attaches to any TCustomEdit control. It filters keyboard input coming to the TCustomEdit control, so that control behaves like a maskedit.

But I encountered another problem. While I can analyze content of clipboard before pasting and then decide whether to paste or not (OnKeyDown event CTRL + V), I am helpless to catch pasting through right-click menu.

I do not want to intercept OnChange Event, because I want to make actions before control's text actually changes.

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Can you listen for WM_PASTE?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I would like to, but how :-) I have no idea how to intercept WM_Paste of another control. Is there a way how to pipe events through this control before they reach attached TCustomEdit control?

Comment: Replace the window procedure. I think you use the WindowProc property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can do what you need by listening for the WM_PASTE message being sent to the target control. The easiest way to do this is to replace the window procedure by means of the WindowProc property.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:

```
  TTextMask = class (TComponent)
  private
    FtempWndProc: TWndMethod;
    FWinControl:TWinControl;
    procedure DoWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
    procedure SetWinControl(Value: TWinControl);
    //...
  published
    //...
    property WinControl : TWinControl read FWinControl write SetWinControl;
  end;

// ...

procedure TTextMask.SetWinControl(Value: TWinControl);
begin
  if Assigned(Value) and  not Assigned(FWincontrol)
      then
            begin
            FtempWndProc := Value.WindowProc;
            Value.WindowProc := DoWindowProc;
            end;
   //...
   FWincontrol:=Value;
end;



procedure TTextMask.DoWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
var s:string;
    Index:Integer;
    m:integer;
begin
   if Message.Msg = WM_Paste then
     begin
     // code here
     end;
   FtempWndProc(Message);
end;
```

Thanx for a good suggestion, David.

Comment: You'll have to restore the original window procedure before your component or the component whose instance is stored in the `FWinControl` field is destroyed.